# How to automatically increment offset in lw mips?

Tags: loops, assembly, mips, offset

I need to iterate through the array below. However the values of the array need to be stored at 0x10010080, but the program needs to start at 0x10010000. Is there a way for me to create a loop that automatically increments the offset by 4, so that the next lw instruction is:

```
lw $t0, 132($s0)
```

```
.data 0x10010080
array: .word 0x10010008, 0x1001000C, 0x10010006, 0x1001000D, 0x10010002

.text
li $s0, 0x10010000

# store the value 0x10010008 in t0 
lw $t0, 128($s0)
```

Comment: A comment describing a load instruction should normally not use the word "store" to describe what it does.  You *load into* registers like t0.

Comment: you should calculate the next memory position to be read...

Answer (score 0):

MIPS has no automatic increment.  Even processors that do (e.g. ARM) require you to request the increment, giving evidence to the argument that it is not really automatic.  However, since MIPS doesn't even have the ability to request increment as part of dereference, then simply increase the value of the pointer by using a separate instruction.

As always, if you cannot do it in one instruction, then use a sequence of one or more.

---

As another point, asking for an instruction that does 128(t0) to become an instruction that is 132(t0) is called self-modifying code.  Older processors supported this concept for two reasons (1) it was necessary because of missing instructions (instructions that take constants but not variables), and (2) because older architectural designs didn't care about code being modified like data — for newer processors, most missing concepts have been provided for in an instruction form, and, due to their more modern designs, they don't like it when code is modified on the fly as it hampers performance or just doesn't work without cache synchronization (which, using it, is also a performance issue).

If you want to access a different location from the first, then use normal/regular array indexing or any other pointer arithmetic to refer to the (new) desired location.

Comment: 128 becoming 132, 136, etc. is something you could do with a *macro*, so there's no run-time loop, just unrolled at assemble time into a sequence of instructions with increasing offset.  If you want a run-time loop, yeah you'd increment the register like a normal person.

Comment: @PeterCordes, there is a [loops] tag, so presumably the loop cannot be fully unrolled, but who knows!